# How can delete all files with a specific extension with cmd batch, excluding 2 specific words? Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to delete with a batch for windows all files with extension `*.jpg` in a folder (`test`) and its subfolder, except two files ex: `abc.jpg` and `xyz.jpg` that occur several times in different folders.

I tried with

```
h:

cd test

for /R %%f in (*.jpg) do (if not "%%~xf"=="abc.jpg" if not "%%~xf"=="'xyz.jpg" del "%%~f")
```

but I failed.

Anyone can help me? Thank you

Comment: Did you perhaps read the help file for the `FOR` command before you posted your question.  I bet if you read the last section about the command modifiers you would have realized what your mistake was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try a `FOR` loop and check to see if the file name is one that should not be deleted. When you are confident that the correct files would be deleted, remove the `echo` from the `DEL` command.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%f IN ('DIR /S /B "C:\src\t\*.jpg"') DO (
    IF NOT "%%~nf" == "abc" IF NOT "%%~nf" == "xyz" (
        echo DEL "%%~f"
    )
)
```

This can also be done in a .bat file script using Powershell. When you are confident that the correct files would be deleted, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Remove-Item` cmdlet.

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter '*.jpg' -exclude 'abc.*','xyz.*' |" ^
        "ForEach-Object { Remove-Item -Path $_ -WhatIf }"
```